# How DialMyApp works on Android devices?

Tags: android

I have recently phone dialed my bank number using an Android device and the following graphical user interface (GUI) popped up on the screen in the place of the traditional call menu:

[image: DialMyApp Itau Bank Screen]

The interface looked like an app with clickable buttons, menus, navbars, forms and figures. In the bottom of the screen was "DialMyApp" which I suppose is the name of this new technology.

With that said...

How this technology works?

Can I build an App like this by myself or is it a proprietary solution or am I tied to their solution?

Since when this feature started working on new Androids?

Comment: this probably impacts the telecom in question being classified as common-carrier. since they are intercepting and now serving content for that endpoint/subscriber that you asked to be connected to, meaning they now answer the same. If you have a lawsuit against itau, tim or whatever other company, now you can include claro for example.

Comment: @gcb interesting line of thought, that is really concerning for them to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s called DialMyApp! It is a B2B app running as a background process checking a phone list of companies that wants you to use Visual IVR instead Voice (cost reasons). Once you install some Community App (could be a telecom company, bank, etc) all of your android calls are verified. If the dialed number is on the list then you will be redirected.

Comment: Oh wow, I got it! The telecom company app is intercepting all my calls and doing the redirection, crazy... Its funny how the telecom app don't tell this functionality is available in the app's description.

Comment: @TiagoStapenhorstMartins I'm kind of horrified by this, it shouldn't be legal

Comment: Recommendation: go to the app store and flag the app for not disclosing it shows advertisements. I explain: play store require apps to disclose if they include methods to profit from user data and behavior. by intercepting your data/behavior and trying to sell you on using the app/whatsapp in exchange of a little fee from the other company (which they save from paying a call center person) they are effectively showing you an Ad (for the other app. in fact, most clicks there will go to the app or app store install page)